# Batch file/command to start a program through command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a program which I want to start using the command prompt and at the same time I want to pass 2 parameters to it.
So, for example, when I wanted to start my program I would open the command prompt (in XP: start > run, type `cmd`, press `return`) and then type:

```
c:\rand\anotherfolder\myprogram.exe 10 20
```

Since I know nothing about batch files, I'm asking two things:

- Can I create a batch file to automatize this process?
- If yes, how :D?

Comment: Could you clarify; do you want a batch file that takes two parameters and passes them to your 'myprogram.exe' or do you want a batchfile that runs 'myprogram.exe' with two fixed values, 10 and 20? Batch files are literally a 'batch' of commands that you'd execute at a command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll edit this if you respond to my comment but if you want to simply execute this command via a batch file (and you know nothing about batch files):

1. Open a text editor (e.g.Notepad)
2. Type in your command (e.g. c:\rand\aotherfolder\myprogram.exe 10 20)
3. Save the file as mybatchfile.cmd
4. Double click the file (in Windows Explorer etc.)

Comment: @plymouth223, How can I ask user to enter values on command prompt, like I dont want to hard code 10,20?